# Authenticating using OATH2 on Azure app registration works fine on IIS express, but fails in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an application that I am trying to add a layer of SSO, authenticating against Azure AD app registration. The code works fine running in IIS Express, but fails with a 400 Bad Request whenever I attempt to run it from any IIS environment, including localhost.

I have a working function that requests an authorisation code, which works with no issues and the code is returned in the querystring. The issue happens in the next stage, where I use that code to retrieve the user's Sub ID from Microsoft. This is the code I have:

```
'Get the base azure values
Dim AzureClient As String = ClientInfo
Dim AzureSecret As String = AzureSecret
Dim AuthRedirectUri As String = "The address of the page"
Dim TenantID As String = AzureTenantID
Dim codeVerifier = Verifier string passed in earlier function


Dim httpWReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" & TenantID & "/oauth2/v2.0/token"), HttpWebRequest)
httpWReq.Method = "POST"
httpWReq.Host = "login.microsoftonline.com"
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Dim postData As String = "client_id=" & AzureClient
postData += "&scope=openid&20email&20profile"
postData += "&code=" & Code
postData += "&redirect_uri=" & AuthRedirectUri
postData += "&grant_type=authorization_code"
postData += "&code_verifier=" & codeVerifier
postData += "&client_secret=" & AzureSecret

Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding()
Dim byteArray As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
httpWReq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
    streamWriter.Write(postData)
End Using

' Get the response.
Dim response As WebResponse = httpWReq.GetResponse() <--- This is where the 400 Bad Request is thrown in IIS, but not IIS Express
Dim responseString As String = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
Dim o As OAuth2AccessTokenReponse = DirectCast(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString, GetType(OAuth2AccessTokenReponse)), OAuth2AccessTokenReponse)
Dim IDToken As String = o.id_token
Dim stream = IDToken
Dim handler = New JwtSecurityTokenHandler()
Dim jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(stream)
Dim tokenS = TryCast(jsonToken, JwtSecurityToken)
Dim subID = tokenS.Claims.First(Function(claim) claim.Type = "sub").Value
Return subID
```

I've compared the calls coming from both environments and they are identical. I have both localhost addresses (localhost IIS address and IIS Express port) so the only differences are the port numbers used in the redirect URI field.

Does anyone have any idea what could be throwing this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem sorted. After much, much digging about I found that IIS was still supporting TLS1.0 - removed that and everything works fine now.